# Which open source or economical framework can be used to create Headless PWA using BigCommerce

Tags: progressive-web-apps, bigcommerce, headless

In my knowledge, Deity Falcon provides ReactJS based framework to implement Headless PWA (Progressive Web App) for BigCommerce but it's Paid. Apart from this, VueStorefront seems good and is open source.

Any suggestion to use better framework with BigCommerce for a growing company to save cost but create an optimal scalable PWA frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue Storefront founder here ;)

I just want to make few clarifications to Sean W post:

1. Vue Storefront is not *just* a community framework. It is backed by a whole company [employing almost 30 people](https://www.vuestorefront.io/about-us) dedicated only to this project PLUS community. We recently got 1,5 mil $ funding and got backed by YCombinator so we are definitely not going anywhere :). We also have active community of more than 4000 developers actively supporting others on our Discord chat and contributing to the project. We also have [the biggest amount of live shops](https://www.similartech.com/technologies/vue-storefront) among all mentioned frameworks. **I'd risk a (slightly biased) statement that together with Next.js Commerce we are the most reliable option on the market.**
2. The last version of Vue Storefront 1 is from a year ago but we are actively developing v2 for almost a year that [gets a new minor version each month](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue-storefront/core) (last is from 5 days) and is aiming to support all major eCommerce platforms (currently it's Commercetools and Magento with Shopify / SFCC / BigCommerce in the making).

If I were you I'd go with either Next.js Commerce if you prefer React or Vue Storefront if you prefer Vue. Both have great communities, vibrant ecosystem and are backed by well-funded companies that are not going anywhere :)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Filip. I am now far ahead through NextJS  and seems the journey is good. I like Vue too but through Vercel Nextjs Commerce got some initial boiler plates to save time as this project is for small company where time to delivery is the major constraint. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.